# Enviar props con link y route desde Grilla

Tags: reactjs, component, parametros, props

Les queria consultar acerca de la duda que me surge sobre el link y el route en React.

Tengo una grilla que se carga con todos mis datos necesarios y un link en cada row.
Ese link tiene un to a la pagina que deseo redirigir.
La pagina a la que me deseo redirigir esta dentro de un route de la siguiente forma.

```
<Route path="/pantalla/:primerparametro"  component={(props) => <pantalla{...props} pepe="variable"/>}></Route>
```

Con el parametro primerparametro y pepe no tengo problemas, los leo perfectamente desde mi segunda pantalla.
Pero como puedo enviar todo el row de la misma forma ?
Mi deseo es que en la pantalla dos pueda disponer de todos los campos de la fila que se selecciono.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es pasar un objeto a ‘to’ en lugar de un string.

```
<Link
    to={{
      pathname: "/pantalla/1", // en lugar de 1 sería tu variable
      row: row
   }}>
    Click To Pass Props
</Link>
```

Supongo que estás usando un map para iterar todos los rows, entonces pasas ese objeto

Aquí no habría cambios:

```
<Route path="/pantalla/:primerparametro"  component={(props) => <pantalla{...props} pepe="variable"/>}></Route>
```

Y en tu pantalla donde quieres leer el row, accederías al row así:

```
this.props.location.row
```

Que sería diferente al tratar de acceder al primerparametro de tu ruta

```
this.props.match.params.primerparametro
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! Excelente.
En primer lugar no sabia: "pasar un objeto a ‘to’ en lugar de un string."
Esto "this.props.location.row" no me funciono tal cual, pero le saque el this y ahi si funciono perfecto!

Comment: Ah ok, entonces estás creando tus componentes con funciones, si es así no se necesita el this.